# JavaFX FileChooser show custom options

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

Is there are a way to show additional controls on the file chooser dialog?
I want something like this:

```
...
File name:    [                                                   ]
Save as type: [                                                   ]

Options (collapsed)
[x] Checkbox     Label: [TextField    ]      Label: [TextField    ]

                                                [ Save ] [ Cancel ]
```

Comment: I think `JavaFX` `FileChooser` is a "what you see is what you get" type of Class due to it being `final`. So, I am guessing the answer is no you can't have any additional controls.

Comment: @Sedrick is correct. The `FileChooser` hooks in the native windowing file chooser, so you are basically stuck with what the OS provides. You can, of course, customize a `Dialog` and implement the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I guess I'll just show a new dialog with the options when the user clicks 'File > Save as...' and then call the FileChooser from that dialog. Or maybe add the item 'File > Export options' and leave the 'Save as...' dialog as it is.